# How to keep elastic search running in Cent OS 6.5?

Tags: elasticsearch, centos

I use the commands:

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.5.2]`
`./bin/elasticsearch & rm -rf`

for starting elastic search from directory `elasticsearch-1.5.2` using terminal SSH.
When I close terminal elastic search is stopped in server.

How to keep elastic search running in Cent OS 6.5

Comment: Why do you have `rm -rf` at the end of your command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [1.5.2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/setup.html), you simply need to start the elasticsearch process with the `-d` switch:

```
./bin/elasticsearch -d
```

The `elasticsearch` process will return immediately and run as a deamon. If you can, though, you should install and run elasticsearch [as a service](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/setup-service.html#_rpm_based_distributions) on your CentOS server.